# Postgresql to handle column

Tags: sql, postgresql, substring

I have a column tags in a table content like this:
**"k8s-azure-created-by": "kubernetes-azure-dd"**,"kubernetes.io-created-for-pv-name": "pvc-cxxx","kubernetes.io-created-for-pvc-name": "data-postgresql-ha-stack-postgresql-2","kubernetes.io-created-for-pvc-namespace": "dblearning"

I wish to get content for this:
"k8s-azure-created-by": "kubernetes-azure-dd"

Or the value for key "k8s-azure-created-by"
kubernetes-azure-dd
That would be best

I wish to get content for this:
"k8s-azure-created-by": "kubernetes-azure-dd"

Or the value for key "k8s-azure-created-by"
kubernetes-azure-dd
That would be best

how to achieve that using sql in postgresql?

I tried substring and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the string into json then extract the element using `->>` :

```
select ('{'|| mycol || '}')::jsonb->>'k8s-azure-created-by' as "k8s-azure-created-by"
from mytable
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/rh_4X7qW)